# Should I not use LINQ to objects because Microsoft might change it?

Tags: c#, linq

I got into an argument with a co-worker about the use of LINQ to Objects (IEnumerable, not IQueryable) in our C# code.  I was using LINQ, and he said that we shouldn't be using an external vendor's (Microsoft) code in our code, but that we should wrap it ourselves in our own layer of abstraction.

Now I understand this methodology for use where you've got a no-name third party dll that may go out of business next week, or when your dealing with database calls (ie. returning a common data provider, rather than a SQL or Oracle specific one), but in my mind the LINQ syntax is too pretty/elegant/readable for Microsoft to abandon in the next 10 years.  It's about as likely to be dropped as the ToString("Hello {0}", firstName); functionality.

I could give up arguing, and implement our own LINQ library that calls the standard LINQ methods under the covers, but isn't this over doing it?  Plus I could only use the extension methods, I have no idea how to be able to wrap this:

```
from e in employees
select new { e.Name, e.Id };
```

What would your argument be, for or against using LINQ to objects (the IEnumerable extension methods)?

Comment: Under that same logic, your co-worker should probably avoid the usage of `List<T>` et al. I've voted to close as Not Constructive as this is ripe for discussion rather than a concrete answer.

Comment: Breaking changes are highly unlikely to happen. Your coworker seems to be one of those over abstracter types.

Comment: My favorite "roll your own" co-worker, is that you?

Comment: Maybe an intentional edit to elicit a concrete answer instead of closure.

Comment: "we shouldn't be using an external vendor's (Microsoft) " - that excludes _all_ of the .NET library...

Comment: ... close nazis. This is absurd to see closed, this is an extremely important question from a developer who is honestly trying to understand what makes sense in real world development. He also had the foresight to inquire from experienced developers when he felt his coworkers statements were suspect.

Comment: @Chris: You are welcome to edit the question to make it more constructive.  As it stands, it's not an answerable question; nobody has a crystal ball here.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I extremely disagree, it is very constructive question. This question is actually one of the most important questions I've seen asked on stackoverflow in months if not over a year.

Comment: The co-worker is an idiot, and the question as stated remains inappropriate for the Q&A format of SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your friend is wrong. LINQ was *the* flagship feature of C# 3.0, and will not be leaving the language. There's always a chance MS will cease to support C# (though I severely doubt that,) but as long as there's a C#, there will be LINQ.

Also, consider in which assembly the LINQ-to-objects extension methods are housed: `System.Core`.

Comment: That's an extremely good point @dlev.  If it's in a dll called System.Core, I don't think Microsoft could send a stronger message to develpers that it's not going anywhere any time soon.

Answer (score 10):

He is completely wrong.
That argument only applies when dealing with fungible components, such as database platforms.

Microsoft is *extremely* careful to avoid making breaking changes in .Net; there is no way that they would drop LINQ.

To answer your other points, query comprehension syntax (`from x in y`) is a compiler feature which is transformed into method calls.
If you write your own methods, the compiler will happily use them.

There are already third party implementations of the LINQ to Objects methods, such as [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) (for use with .Net 2.0, which predates LINQ), or [EduLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/) (written for  educational purposes)

Comment: Everything might change. It only applies when things are LIKELY to change, and the cost of dealing with the change is greater than the cost of dealing with the additional layer of abstraction that tries to shield you from the change (including the cost of designing, writing, testing and maintaining it).

Answer (score 8):

> I was using LINQ, and he said that we shouldn't be using an external vendor's (Microsoft) code in our code, but that we should wrap it ourselves in our own layer of abstraction.

It's a core part of the language (i.e., part of the C# language specification). It'll be around as long as C# is around. Changes to it would be breaking changes, and would be a massive cost to Microsoft's customers. They are not going to do this.

Comment: Well, Microsoft has radically changed languages in the past, such as going from VB6 to VB.NET.  Yes, they tried to make it as compatible as possible, but there were many breaking changes.  Most (including myself) would say that the changes were good things and were needed.  However, it's unlikely that any change will happen within 10 years.

Comment: VB.NET was a new language, not the next version of VB6

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping a layer dependency like ADO.NET or a third-party library: idea worth considering.

Wrapping LINQ to Objects (core part of framework and game-changer): bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your co-worker simply feels that this is **more** correct:

```
var result = employees.Select(e => new { e.Name, e.Id });
```

Regardless, I think your co-worker's worries are completely unfounded.

...*interesting*...

Comment: Nope, he is against the use of var because it's "lazy", and his argument was over the use of the linq extension methods.

Comment: @Daryl: I thought it was a little weird to use at first ...so I can understand the apprehension to use something that seems to defy type-safety at first glance. Until I understood what `var` was, I didn't want to use it although it looked like everyone was. He's just gotta get over it.